# Highstock graph shows points instead of line at certain zoom levels

Tags: highcharts

I am using a Highcharts Stock graph to show a percentage with respect to time.

http://jsfiddle.net/michaelchart/yYmPR/1/

At certain zoom levels (in this case, when zooming to a timespan of between about 6 and 12 years) the plot strangely turns from a line to sporadic points.

Any ideas as to why this might be? Or is it a bug with Highstock?

You can see an example of a working Highstock graph here http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/basic-line.

Comment: Weird: when setting <div id="container" style="height: 400px; width: 826px"></div> (note that I use width and not min-width here), it works perfectly; at 827px it does not.

Comment: Actually it does not work perfectly either. Maybe you should have a look at highchart's data grouping feature. By adding  "plotOptions: { series: { dataGrouping: {  units: [     ['month', [1] ]  ]    }  }   }," to your chart definition it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After posting on the Highstock forum and consequently having an issue posted on github, I found that it was because of the default value of the `gapSize` option. According to [the docs](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/ref/#plotOptions-line--gapSize);

> gapSize : Number
>   Defines when to display a gap in the graph. A gap size of 5 means that if the distance between two points is greater than five times that of the two closest points, the graph will be broken.
>
> In practice, this option is most often used to visualize gaps in time series. In a stock chart, intraday data is available for daytime hours, while gaps will appear in nights and weekends.
>
> Defaults to 5.

Setting `gapSize` to null [fixes the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/yYmPR/2/).

Answer (score 0):

In my particular case, the reason of this problem was bad data output.
Within "series" property, within the "data" array there was a "false" value.

Example:

```
series : {
   "type":"column",
   "name":"Test",
   "data":[541,784,false,251,353]
}
```

Corrected the problem in the backend so "false" was interpreted as 0, and everything works now.